# Dropdown menu table, where the second column value depends on the first column value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My copany asked me to develop a website for inside use. The website contains a form with multiple rows and columns of dropdown menus.

The first column contains the type of the product we are selling, while the second column contains the sub-type of the device. (for example: Type1 - Model1, or Type1 - Model2)

The purpose of having multiple rows is so we can upload multiple devices at the same time.
So far, I've come up with this:

```
  <tr><td><select name="category">
      <option value="0">-</option>
      <option value="1">Type1</option>
      <option value="2">Type2</option>
      <option value="3">Type3</option>
      <option value="4">Type4</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><select name="items">
      <option value="3">-</option>
  </select> </td> </tr>
  <tr><td><select name="category">
      <option value="0">-</option>
      <option value="1">Type1</option>
      <option value="2">Type2</option>
      <option value="3">Type3</option>
      <option value="4">Type4</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><select name="items">
      <option value="3">-</option>
  </select> </td> </tr>
```

And the script part:

```
var categories = {
  "-": [{value: '3',text: '-'}],
  "Type1": [{value: '1',text: 'model1'}, {value: '2',text: 'model2'}],
  "Type2": [{value: '4',text: 'model3'}, {value: '10',text: 'model4'}],
  "Type3": [{value: '6',text: 'model5'},{value: '6',text: 'model6'}, {value: '7',text: 'model7'}],
  "Type4": [{value: '8',text: 'model8'}, {value: '9',text: 'model9'}, {value: '11',text: 'model10'}, {value: '12',text: 'model11'}, {value: '13',text: 'DELUXE EDITION'}]
};

function selectchange() {
  var select = $('[name=items]');
  select.empty();

  $.each(categories[$(':selected', this).text()], function() {
    select.append('<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.text + '</option>');
  });
}
$(function() {
  $('[name=category]').on('change', selectchange);
});
```

I dont need a database, as the list of products and models will not change significantly.
My problem is: Whenever I change the second row sub-type for example, the first row sub-type changes as well. What should I modify in the script to make every row behave individually?
(The best would be if i could $_post all values as an array.)

Working JFiddle example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L2cwqrus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both your pairs of `<select>` elements have the same names. When you do `$('[name=items]')`, JQuery selects *all* elements which match and then your `.append()` calls append items to both dropdown menus.

Here's a JSFiddle which uses separate names for each pair of dropdowns to illustrate one solution: https://jsfiddle.net/prutbkr8/

Answer (score 0):

The field names need to be different on each row - e.g., category_1, items_1, category_2, items_2.

In order to avoid having to repeat the selectchange() function (e.g., selectchange_1, selectchange_2, etc.), add a class (e.g., class="category") to all the category_xx fields and instead of $('[name=category]').on('change'... use $('.category').on('change'... and pass the the number from the id to selectchange().